# Re-center map on resize - google API v2

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, google-maps-api-2

I've been trying to get a google map to re-center after a browser resize, otherwise part of the map is hidden.  But having little luck.

http://www.talesfromthesaddle.com/newmap/current-position/

I had worked out an iframe refresh, but obviously this resets the map, if you have moved things around, zoomed in or whatever.  So, I've been trying to use checkResize, but just not sure where to slot it into the complicated script (it's a plugin).

```
$ret.=$this->map_id.".checkResize();\n";
```

Full script of the plugin is :
http://www.talesfromthesaddle.com/newmap/wp-content/plugins/xml-google-maps/xmlgooglemaps_googleMapsAPI.php

Would appreciate any help.

Comment: http://www.talesfromthesaddle.com/newmap/wp-content/plugins/xml-google-maps/mlgooglemaps_googleMapsAPI.txt Text file of the PHP to view in browser.

Comment: Why are you using the deprecated (and turned off) [Google Maps API v2](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference)?

Comment: Because I can't rewrite the whole plugin